# Error in loading Dropbox path

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dropbox

I have to load a document from some folders in Dropbox. This is the error:

```
DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/sandbox/lets/newFile.json - File not found
```

but the folders are their and even the document!!

If I search this instead:

```
/sandbox/newFile.json
```

(I copied the newFile.json even in sandbox folder).
It seems that there is an error in loading other folders in sandbox folder. How can I fix the error??

This is how I download the document:

```
 [self.restClient loadFile:filename2 intoPath:getImagePath2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this error is generated because the app is set to only folder access. if you want to access all the folders, you must have a full dropbox access